# onblur and onfocus after javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an input form

```
<input id="txtSearch" class="txtSearch" name="SearchPhraseText" type="text"http value="<%= ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.SITEMATER_ENTER_SEARCH_TERM %>" onfocus="handleSearchFocus(this)" onblur="handleSearchBlur(this)" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13 ) {search();}"/>
```

When I add the following to $(document).ready in my javascript..

```
if ( window.location.search.indexOf( "search" ) != -1){
    $('#txtSearch').val( "<%= Session["SearchPhrase"] %>"v);
}
```

given that I have this elsewhere in my javascript

```
     function handleSearchFocus(searchBox) {

        if ($(searchBox).val() == "<%= ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.SITEMATER_ENTER_SEARCH_TERM%>") {
           $(searchBox).val("");
           $(searchBox).css("color", "black");
        }

    }

    function handleSearchBlur(searchBox) {
        if ($(searchBox).val() == "" ) {
           $(searchBox).css("color", "gray");
           $(searchBox).val("<%= ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.SITEMATER_ENTER_SEARCH_TERM%>"); //should reference config file
        }

    }
```

Those two functions for handling focus and blur no longer work. The aren't run when I click on the input box or click away. What I'm trying to do is if there is a search value that should be displayed, display it. If not, it follows the logic in the blur/focus functions above.

Comment: Any Javascript errors? Have you confirmed that the functions aren't executing at all, rather than just not doing anything because the `if` conditions aren't met?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You have `type="text"http` in your input tag, which might not cause problems, but is incorrect. You also have a stray "v" in `$('#txtSearch').val( "<%= Session["SearchPhrase"] %>"v);`, which I suppose could be a typo or copy/paste error, but if it's in your code, it'll cause a problem.

Comment: One sidenote: Consider caching your searchBox as a jQuery object. EX: var $searchBox = $(searchBox) then you wont have to call the main jQuery function 2 additional times.

Comment: Ahh, how did I not notice those errors. I think the one of the errors in the javascript caused some problems, and I was getting reference errors saying the blur/focus functions didn't exist.

edit: I'll look into cachine the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting your code in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t2djh/) and got the following errors in the Developer Tools console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSearchFocus is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSearchBlur is not defined

Note that I set jsFiddle to run the script `onLoad`, which is what I'm assuming you're doing with your code.

Usually, you would run your code `onLoad` because you need all the elements to finish loading in order to manipulate and grab the elements on the page. In your situation, you need the opposite to happen. Your elements are created with your `onfocus` and `onblur` events tied to your functions. However, those functions do not exist yet and so they cannot be fired. Notice that your functions work if you change the jsFiddle `onLoad` to `no wrap (body)`.

In other words, **the elements are trying to find the functions before they are available**.

You need to either put your functions in `<script>` tags in the body (after the element), or attach it to the event in your `$(document).ready` code, like so:

```
$('#txtSearch').focus(function () {
    // code here
});
$('#txtSearch').blur(handleSearchBlur);
```

Answer (score 0):

MrOBrian caught the errors that caused this in the question comments.